# JQuery not auto populating field elements with data

Tags: c#, jquery, model-view-controller

I have the following code:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name, new { @onload = "if(this.value=='')this.value='NAME';", @class = "text", @onblur = "if(this.value=='')this.value='NAME';", @onfocus = "if(this.value=='NAME')this.value='';" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email, new { @onload = "if(this.value=='')this.value='EMAIL ADDRESS';", @class = "text", @onblur = "if(this.value=='')this.value='EMAIL ADDRESS';", @onfocus = "if(this.value=='EMAIL ADDRESS')this.value='';" })
```

But it only says 'NAME' when the box is clicked on, I want it to be there to begin with.

Comment: I don't see where this has anything to do with jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just use the HTML5 placeholder attribute? That seems to be what you're trying to do.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name, new { placeholder = "NAME" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email, new { placeholder = "EMAIL ADDRESS" })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the attribute of HTML5 placeholder and the plugin [jquery-placeholder](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder) for compatibility with other browsers

Html + Razor:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name, new { placeholder = "NAME", @class="with-placeholder" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email, new { placeholder = "EMAIL ADDRESS", @class="with-placeholder"})
```

JS:

```
$('.with-placeholder').placeholder();
```

Data from: [html5please.com](http://html5please.com/)